# Custom empty screen for ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am working on  [Line Chart](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#LineChart)  in [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). I am trying to show chart if there is data and if not, I want to show `No Data Available` instead of empty chart.

**HTML**

```html
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData">
  <canvas  baseChart width="400" height="400"
    [datasets]="lineChartData"
    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="lineChartType"
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**TS**

```js
public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
];
public lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
```

Checkout [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template)

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-jgw2mw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check data variable length like

### html

```
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData[0]['data'].length">
  <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
    [datasets]="lineChartData"
    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="lineChartType"
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>

<div *ngIf="lineChartData[0]['data'].length === 0 ">
  No Data Available
</div>
```

### ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [], label: 'Series A' },
  ];
}
```

Comment: How to do it with pie chart (https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart), I tried with `*ngIf="pieChartData[0].length"` but not working

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`*ngIf`'s `else` block](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```html
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData; else elseBlock">
  <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
    [datasets]="lineChartData"
    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="lineChartType"
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>No Data Available.</ng-template>
```

[Stackbliz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-9bxsuu?file=src/app/app.component.html).

If `lineChartData` can be just empty (`[]`) and you wish to also hide the chart in this case, you can use:

```html
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData && lineChartData.length; else elseBlock">
```

[Stackblitz demo 2 here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-ez6yor?file=src/app/app.component.html)

And/or if you want to guard the `data` variable as well, do:

```html
<div style="display: block;" *ngIf="lineChartData && lineChartData.length && lineChartData[0].data.length; else elseBlock">
```

[Demo here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-efiknr?file=src/app/app.component.html)